# look up user in AD using text file and export to CSV

Tags: powershell, active-directory

Trying to look up a user by DisplayName from a txt file and trying to export it to a CSV.

The expected goal is to have a list of LastName, FirstName (displaynames.txt), have it return an exported CSV file with the information in the "Format-Table" within the code.

Here's the code I've tried

```
ForEach ($DN in (Get-Content -Path c:\displaynames.txt))
{  Get-ADUser -Filter { displayName -like "*$DN*" } -SearchBase "DC=DOMAIN,DC=NET" | Format-Table Surname,GivenName,SamAccountName,UserPrincipalName | Out-File C:\UserAD.csv
}
```

the file returns blank.  Thoughts?  much appreciated in advance

Comment: `Format-Table` outputs to the console, it doesn't output to a file. If you change your `Format-Table` to `Select-Object` and pipe that to `Export-Csv` you will get better results

Comment: Also, if you don't try to format the output or send it to a file, do you get any output in the console? You need to determine if the problem is with the output, or with the search itself.

Comment: I put in this code and it comes back with a result

Get-ADUser -Filter { displayName -like "*LastName, FirstName*" } -SearchBase "DC=DOMAIN,DC=NET" | Format-Table Surname,GivenName,SamAccountName,UserPrincipalName | Out-File C:\Windows\Temp\UserAD.csv

I get results back in the CSV file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give this a try, as [Jonathan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70035952/look-up-user-in-ad-using-text-file-and-export-to-csv#comment123804375_70035952) mentioned in his comment, `Format-Table` is meant to display formatted information to the console and, even though you can use it to export the formatted information to a file it will definitely not be a `CSV`.

The other potential problem on your code, is that `C:\UserAD.csv` is getting replaced on each iteration of the loop because `Out-File` doesn't have the `-Append` switch.

```
Get-Content -Path c:\displaynames.txt | ForEach-Object {
    if(-not [string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($_))
    {
        Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(displayName=*$_*)" -SearchBase "DC=NWIE,DC=NET"
    }
} | Select-Object Surname, GivenName, SamAccountName, UserPrincipalName |
Export-Csv path/to/csv.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: @R3d happy to help!